# Single Sign On using NTLMv1 or NTLMv2 or kerberos to a Spring webapp on tomcat on linux

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, kerberos, ntlm, ntlmv2

We make an appliance with a spring web interface running on Tomcat on Centos Linux.

I'm investigating how we users can connect with out entering a username/password, but instead use windows authentication over http (aka SPNEGO).

as available options mentioned in other SO questions I'm seeing:

- NTLMv1 but not NTLMv2 via [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/faq.html)
- NTLMv1+NTLMv2+kerberos via [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/) but only for windows :(
- Kerberos only via ["Spring Security Kerberos Extension"](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/)

none of which sounds like a reliable all around SSO option for tomcat on Centos.
also much of the information on these projects is over a year old so it's hard to know if these limits still apply.

What is a viable option for SSO on linux these days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option three works perfectly here with Spring 3.0. Go for it!

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be the "ntlmv2-auth" Java library:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmv2auth/

It also includes an SSO servlet filter.